# How to remove unnecessary data from listView?

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So, I'm new to Xamarin and to get some experience I want to write an App that reminds me about upcoming appointments I've saved. For that purpose, I've created a list of upcoming appointments. However, I do not know how to automatically remove an appointment from the list once it lies in the past.
The relevant xaml file looks like this:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:constants="clr-namespace:XamarinFormsSample;assembly=XamarinFormsXamlSample"
x:Class="My.View.AppointmentCalendarView"
Title="AppointmentCalendarPage">
  <ListView x:Name="AppointmentView">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <TextCell Text="{Binding AppointmentDate}: {Binding AppointmentType}" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

With the list defined by

```
    {
    public class AppointmentCalendarPage : ContentPage
    {
        ListView AppointmentView = new ListView();
        ObservableCollection<Appointment> appointments = new ObservableCollection<Appointment>();
        public AppointmentCalendarPage()
        {
            AppointmentView.ItemsSource = appointments;
            Appointments.Add(new Appointment { ID = 0, Host = 0, AppointmentDate = new DateTime(2016, 12, 24), AppointmentType = "Christmas" });
        }

    }
}
```

From that last part, the relevant data in the Appointment class should also be clear.

What do I do on the MV or M side to handle the case of appointments passing?

Comment: You can remove from the observable collection.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms654938(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

As Rohit suggested, you can remove the items from the observable collection. The question when to do is, is another issue. I suggest you take a look at the [App lifecycle of the app](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/app-lifecycle/), in Xamarin Forms.

On the resume of your App, you can do the right operation.